# Uniform convergence to 0

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_n)_\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ converging to $0$.

The functions are such that for all $x$, $(f_n(x))_\mathbb{N}$ is decreasing.

How can one show that the $f_n$ converge *uniformly* to $0$ ?

---

What I got so far :

Let $x_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)=\sup\{f_n(x)\}$, we suppose that $f_n(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$.

As it's a decreasing, bounded sequence, it has a limit $l\neq0$.

Now I wanted to have a contradiction there, but I can't manage to find one :  I tried to show that $l>0$ implied that $\exists x,\forall n,f(x)\ge l$ but that didn't work out.

Comment: what is the domain of the $f_n$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Oops, forgot that. Edited.

Comment: Apply [Dini's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) or imitate its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(f_n)$ is decreasing to $0$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, we have

$$[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} E_n,$$

where $E_n := \{x\in [0,1] : f_n(x) < \varepsilon\}$. In fact, since $(f_n)$ is decreasing,  $(E_n)$ is increasing. Hence, $\cap_{n \ge N} E_n = E_N$ for all $N$. Furthermore, since $f_n$ is continuous for each $n$, $E_n$ is open for each $n$. Hence, $\{E_n\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, finitely many $E_n$ cover $[0,1]$. Let $n_1,\ldots, n_k$ be indices for which $[0,1] \subseteq E_{n_1} \cup \cdots \cup E_{n_k}$. Set $m = \max\{n_1,\ldots, n_k\}$. Then $[0,1] \subseteq E_m$. Thus, for all $n \ge m$, $|f_n(x)| = f_n(x) \le f_m(x) < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true.  Consider the functions $f_n(x) = x/n$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: See my edit, I forgot to add the domain sorry.

Comment: The interval is $[0,1]$. And by Dini's lemma it is true.